# IOS NotificationContentExtension background color to match the theme

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

[image]Hello
When creating [NotificationContentExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension) I can control the background color. I can also detect if the user has a dark or light theme.

I'd like to change the contentExtension background to either dark or light background to match the iPhone colors.

How can I get (preferably in runtime) the colors of the theme? Just to be clear - in the image attached you can see the notification has a "dark" header. I'd like to know the color of it exactly so I can match the content to be the same color. (instead of the current "black" color)

Comment: Why don't you just run the app in simulator first, get the color of extension using **Digital Color Meter** in Mac and use that particular color as extension's background.

Comment: Because i'm not sure the color will always stay the same. What youre suggesting clearly will work. But might create issues in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIColor.systemBackground`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/ui_element_colors

Comment: Yes! Thanks exactly what I needed